# No Python IDE will start and it will not start in the Command Prompt

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-prompt

When I click on my Python IDE's (IDEL, PyScripter) they will not even open. I tried typing *python* in the command prompt and this is what happened:

```
C:\>python
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site.py", line 548, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site.py", line 537, in main
        aliasmbcs()
      File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site.py", line 469, in aliasmbcs
        codecs.lookup(enc)
      File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 85, in search_function
        norm_encoding = normalize_encoding(encoding)
      File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 57, in normalize_encoding`enter code here`
        encoding = str(encoding, "ascii")
    TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you recently install ArcGIS? It looks to me like ArcGIS installed a few libraries, and overwrote your site.py, but it's using code that's meant for Python3 rather than Python2.7. The `str` function is capable of taking in 2 arguments in Python3 but not in Python2.

To get your Python to work again, you could try deleting the entire ArcGIS10.5 directory from your computer (or temporarily moving it to your desktop and seeing if that helps). You can also try running `python -S` in Command Prompt to run Python without importing site.py.

To try to get ArcGIS working, you might be able to install Python3, and reinstall ArcGIS using that.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I reinstalled Python and now my IDE's work. The only thing that does not work is the _Python (command line)_ application.

Comment: I have another question, my work computer **was** running Python 3.6 however the folder said Python27, does Python always download into a Python27 folder?

Comment: Usually only Python 2.7 downloads into a folder called Python27. Is it possible that you had two versions of Python installed, and Python3 just happened to be the one that ran?